# Using AWS as certificate store

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, certificate

I have an application that generates PDF documents and sign them. The signature requires a certificate.

I would like to avoid certificate management headache (securing storage, access, etc). Therefore, I wonder if it possible to use AWS ACM for that? For example, loading the certificate from ACM at application startup.

In AWS ACM documentation, I see there is a Java SDK that allows me to get a certificate remotely. However, I'm not sure if it also includes the private key which I need to sign the PDF documents.

Answer (score 2):

ACM does not allow you to access the private key of your certificates.  Only ELB, ALB, and CloudFront have access to the private keys.  So it's not a fit, here.

[EC2 Systems Manager Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) should provide exactly what you need, though.

It is a hierarchical key/value encrypted store where each "parameter" (value) is (optionally) encrypted at rest.  IAM permissions allow granular access control to specific parameters.  The values can be up to 4096 characters, each, the hierarchy supports 5 levels, and has nice compliance controls.  If you change a parameter, it automatically tracks when and who made the change.

The parameter store is available regardless of whether you are actually using anything else in EC2 Systems Manager.